# python, urllib2 weird error?

Tags: python, urllib2

friends.

I'm trying to rewrite one of my little tools. basically, it gets an input from user, and if that input doesn't contain the "base url" a function will construct that input into a valid url for other part of the program to work on.

if I were wrote it so the program only accepts valid url as input, it will work; however if I pass a string and construct it, urllib2.urlopen() will fail, and I have no idea why, as the value return is exactly the same str value...

```
import urllib2
import re

class XunLeiKuaiChuan:

    kuaichuanBaseAddress = 'http://kuaichuan.xunlei.com/d/'
    regexQuery = 'file_name=\"(.*?)\"\sfile_url=\"(.*?)\sfile_size=\"(.*?)\"'
    agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2)'

    def buildLink(self, aLink):

        if aLink == '':
            return

        if 'xunlei.com' not in aLink:
            aLink = self.kuaichuanBaseAddress + aLink

        return aLink

    def decodeLink(self, url):
        url = self.buildLink(url) #it will return correct url with the value provided.
        print 'in decodeLink ' + url  
        urlReq = urllib2.Request(url)
        urlReq.add_header('User-agent', self.agent)
        pageContent = urllib2.urlopen(urlReq).read()
        realLinks = re.findall(self.regexQuery, pageContent)
        return realLinks


test = XunLeiKuaiChuan()
link='y7L1AwKuOwDeCClS528'
link2 = 'http://kuai.xunlei.com/d/y7L1AwKuOwDeCClS528'
s = test.decodeLink(link2)
print s
```

when I call it with link2 it will function as expected. and will fail when use 'link' someone tell me what I miss here? my "old version" work with only accept full url, but this unknown behavior is killing me here......Thank you.

btw if with full url it returns an empty list, just open the url and enter the catcha on the page. they do it to prevent some kind of 'attacks'....

Comment: What happens when it fails? Is there an error/traceback?

Comment: Are you sure the host names are correct? You are using a different hostname in `link2` than you are in the base address defined.

Comment: I just realized that by looking once again in the code -__-

Comment: thank you for pointing it out, the host name is incorrect in building function...lol

Answer (score 0):

never mind I got hostname in the code wrong.